# spectral decomposition of A+B in terms of A and B eigenvalues/eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A and B are symmetric matrices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , then $A=V_1 D_1 V_1^t$ and $B=V_2 D_2 V_2^t$ where $V_1,V_2$ are orthonormal matrices of eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $D_1,D_2$ diagonal matrizes with the eigenvalues.
$A+B$ is obviously symmetric. I want to know if there is a way to get the spectral decompostion of A+B in terms of $D_1,D_2,V_1,V_2$?

Comment: This is a very hard question, I believe, which was only fully solved in 2001, see this article: https://www.ams.org/notices/200102/fea-knutson.pdf.  Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can summarize the main points for you.

Comment: @Vincent Those results only give inequalities regarding these eigenvalues. In short, those results confirm a sort of converse to the [Weyl inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_about_perturbation).

Comment: @Maoban There are algorithms that are useful [when either $A$ or $B$ has a low rank](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143375/34894), but more generally there doesn't seem to be an approach that's faster than simply calculating the eigenvalues of $A + B$ from scratch